# Can jstl check if attribute has been added to the model?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, el

Is it possible to check if an attribute has been added to the model?

```
//in the controller teh variable is not always added
//
model.addAttribute("variable", myVariable);
```

and in the jsp something like this

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${variable is present}">
        Not present
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        Present
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSTL/EL cannot check if an attribute has been added to the model. For that you need to implement an observer/observable yourself.

EL can however check if a bean property or a map value is not null or empty.

```
<c:when test="${not empty bean.property}">
```

---

```
<c:when test="${not empty map.key}">
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE tutorial - Overview of EL operators](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html)
- [Java EE tutorial - Examples of EL expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the attribute is empty

```
<c:if test="${not empty post}">
   <h3>${post.title}</h3>   
</c:if>
```